# How to disable Google Assistant without being logged into account?

Tags: google-account, google-assistant

I am unable to disable Google Assistant without being logged into an account.  When I try to, I am stuck with the following:

> Sign in to make the Google Assistant yours.
>
> Your assistant knows you by your Google Account and can help you with your calendar, ...

Is there a way to disable Google Assistant without being logged into an account?

Comment: Google Assistant, as everything else Google, requires a Google account. If you aren't logged in then GA won't work. Most would consider that state as "disabled".

Comment: @ChanganAuto If a device is under MDM (AKA no particular Google account), Google Assistant allows containment to be breached when device is in kiosk mode (device locked down) = not so locked down.  https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this one. I don't have a Google account activated on the phone and it keeps pestering me with this message. It's like "you can choose not to use what've decided to force you to use, but don't think we're not going to pester you obnoxiously about it for the rest of your life if you say 'no'".